# Trying to align content in a div on a center

Tags: html, css, positioning, markup

This should be trivial, but given the granularity with which I am styling my markup, I am unable to get the content in the center

Markup is essentially:

```
<div class = "rectangle" id = "login">
    <form>
     <!-- bunch of labels and corresponding input fields -->
    </form>
</div>
```

The stylesheet is essentially:

```
.rectangle{ border:1px solid #ccc; width:500px; padding: 10px;}
#login{margin:auto;}
#login form {margin:auto;}
```

This unfortunately does not center align the contents my form. They are closer to the left of the containing parent element (div class rectangle). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you want to center all inputs within form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

**CSS**

```
.rectangle{ 
    border:1px solid #ccc; 
    width:500px; 
    padding: 10px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class = "rectangle" id = "login">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="txt1" />
        <input type="text" name="txt2" />        
    </form>
</div>​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/BzAVp/).